# How to import external es6 module and bundle into build

Tags: import, build, bundle, cdn, vite

When `socket.io` is imported from a CDN like this instead of npm install:

```js
import sio from 'https://unpkg.com/socket.io-client@4.5.1/dist/socket.io.esm.min.js'
```

After `vite build` the url persist and the source from the url is not bundled, but still loaded from the url - also after build.

Is it possible to bundle the source of the url into the source of the build, using vite?